# Triggered Send using REST API with Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, ampscript

I would like to substitute some variables in my email template using SFMC's REST API.

For example, in my email:

```
%%[Substitute_var1]%%
```

When I call it through REST, how it's possible to substitute this variable?

Comment: I might need a little more information - is this variable in a data extension? Are you passing this variable at send time? Not quite sure what you are asking.

Comment: Yes This variable is in data extension and wanted to add it in send time

Comment: Did this end up answering your question?  If so can we get it marked answered?

Comment: Hi @Pravin - did this question get answered?  Just want to make sure we solved your issue here - would you mind checking the mark if so, or possibly update us with any new issues?

Answer (score 0):

The REST call to send a triggered message does not provide the ability to update a data extension.  It does allow you to update "send time attributes' for a subscriber, and those are passed in as the `to:` section of the payload:

```
  "To":{
     "Address":"example1@example.com",
     "SubscriberKey":"example1@example.com",
     "ContactAttributes":{
        "SubscriberAttributes":{
           "Region":"West", //passed in at send time
           "City":"Indianapolis", //passed in at send time
           "Substitute_var1":"Value" //passed in at send time
        }
     }
  }
```

These attributes for the subscriber will need to be created prior to sending.