# Exact Target Rest Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, fuel-sdk

Last update I've seen was from over a year ago:
[Exact Target Triggered Send using REST API with Data Extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24347/exact-target-triggered-send-using-rest-api-with-data-extension)

Only documentation I've found:
https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html

Is it still not possible to update a data extension during a triggered send call?

Is anyone still working on Exact Target?

Comment: Either an expired token or a comma at the end of a property caused a 400.  Adding the data to subscriber attributes updated the data extension tied to the triggered send.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what data you want to update during a Triggered Send, however there are a couple of options for you:

1. Select a "Triggered Send" Data Extension in the Subscriber Management section when configuring the Triggered Send. Note that **this will only work with Triggered Send Data Extensions**. Use the "Triggered Send" Data Extension template when creating the Data Extension
2. Include `UpdateDE()`, `UpsertDE()` or `InsertDE()` [AMPScript functions](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/) in your email template to update, upsert or insert records in a Data Extension at send time.

Comment: UpsertDE() doesn't work for us. Causes the send to error out. Added a function to look and see if the user is in the data extension, if user does exist -> UpdateDE(), else -> InsertDE(). That didn't work either.